# The Hessian of a smooth function in local coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensors

I would like to confirm that the Hessian of a smooth function $f\colon U\to \mathbb R$ that is defined on an open subset $U\subset M$ of a smooth manifold $M$ is in local coordinates given by $$\nabla^2 f = \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j} dx_i\otimes dx_j - \sum_{j,k}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\omega_{jk}\otimes dx_k$$

Unfortunately, I am still having a hard time doing these kind of problems. I really hope someone could give me a hint.

### What I know:

I know that $$\nabla^2_{X,Y} f = XYf - (\nabla_XY)f$$ $$\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} = \sum_k\Gamma^k_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}$$ and $$\nabla\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} = \sum_k\omega_{kj}\otimes
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}$$

### What I tried:

So I've tried expressing $X$ resp. $Y$ in terms of local coordinates s.t. $$X= \sum_i X_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i},\ Y= \sum_j Y_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$$ and computing $\nabla^2_{X,Y}f$ accordingly but that didn't seem to be what I'm supposed to do.

Then I tried writing $XYf = X(Yf) = X(\nabla_Yf)$ with respect to $X = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}, Y =\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ but that approach wasn't succesfull either.

I had the impression that the most reasonable approach was to express $df = \sum_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}dx_j$ and then compute

\begin{align}
 \nabla df = \nabla\left(\sum_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}dx_j\right) 
 &= \sum_j \nabla \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}dx_j\right) \\ &= \sum_j \left(\nabla\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\otimes dx_j + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\nabla dx_j\right) \\ 
 &= \sum_j \left(\sum_i\omega_{ij}\otimes \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \otimes dx_j + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\nabla dx_j\right) \\ 
 &= \sum_j \left(\sum_i\omega_{ij}\otimes \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \otimes dx_j - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\sum_k \omega_{kj}\otimes dx_k \right) \\ 
 &= \sum_j \left(\sum_i\omega_{ij}\otimes \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \otimes dx_j - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\sum_k \omega_{kj}\otimes dx_k\right) \\ 
 &= \sum_{i,j} \omega_{ij}\otimes \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \otimes dx_j - \sum_{j,k}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \omega_{kj}\otimes dx_k
\end{align}

### Edit:

I've added more steps and it seems that I'm quite close. The problematic part here is the left hand side. I think the only choice I have is trying to express $$\omega_{kj} = \sum_i\Gamma^k_{ij}dx_i$$ but how do get to $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}$?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: A couple of points:  (1) The expression $$\nabla df = \nabla\left(\sum_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}dx_j\right)$$ should read $$\nabla df = \nabla\left(\sum_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}dx_j\right)$$ (3) Also note that $\nabla(dx^i) = -\omega_{kj} dx^k$ (sum over repeated indices) . I think if you redo the calculation with these in mind, it will come out ok.

Comment: Thank you very much ahersh23, is my last equation correct so far? I already tried plugging in $\nabla(dx_j)$ as you suggested, but somehow didn't get much further. But the last equation (including your suggestion) will get it done?

Comment: I've added additional steps I did, the right hand side looks fine, it's the left hand side that I didn't manage to get any further.

Comment: The mistake is in moving from the 2nd to 3rd equation: $\nabla(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}) = d(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j})$ . Expand that out and you should get what you want

Comment: I've noticed there was still a missing $f$ in the first line, do you mean there is a mistake in the second line? Is $\nabla(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}) = d(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j})$ valid? Sorry I'm confused where exactly I went wrong.

Comment: Yes $\nabla(g) = dg$ is valid for any smooth function $g$. Expand out $d(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j})$.

Comment: And yes, $$\nabla^2 f = \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j} dx_i\otimes dx_j - \sum_{j,k}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\omega_{jk}\otimes dx_k$$ should read:
 $$\nabla^2 f = \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j} dx_i\otimes dx_j - \sum_{j,k}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\omega_{jk}\otimes dx_k$$

Comment: To be completely explicit, the error is here:
$$  \sum_j \left(\nabla\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\otimes dx_j + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\nabla dx_j\right) \\  = \sum_j \left(\sum_i\omega_{ij}\otimes \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \otimes dx_j + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\nabla dx_j\right) $$

Comment: sorry ahersh23, how exactly do I correctly expant $\nabla \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$? Isn't $\nabla\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} = \sum \omega_{ij}\otimes \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ correct?

Comment: @Zest notice that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}$ is a real smooth function, it is not a vector field. So $\nabla \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}$ is the gradient of that smooth function, it is not the covariant derivative of a vector field (and so you cannot expand it like I did in the remark in my answer).

Comment: $\nabla(g) = d(g) = \sum_{i} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i} dx^{i} $

Comment: ahhh, okay, now it makes sense! Finally, thanks so much guys! Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome! Also, you should be sure you fully understand where the minus sign comes from in the expression $\nabla(dx^{i}) = -\omega_{kj} dx^{k}$ . (that's a good exercise too).

Comment: This should come from the skew-symmetry of $\omega_{kj}$ with respect to orthonormal frames, shouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry guys, I have one last question, for the smooth function $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ am I correct in assuming that $$\nabla \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \sum_j  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}dx_j\quad ?$$

Comment: It doesn't come from skew-symmetry. What @ahersh23 meant, explicitly, is that $$\nabla_{\bullet} \mathrm{d} x^i = - \sum_{1 \leq b \leq n} \omega_{b}^i (\bullet) \mathrm{d} x^b$$ This is a consequence of the definition of the covariant derivative of a $1$-form

Comment: And yes, you're right about the gradient of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ being able to be expressed that way. This is a consequence of the fact that for any smooth function $h$, we have $$\nabla h = \sum_{1 \leq j \leq n} (\partial_i h) \mathrm{d} x^i$$

Comment: Your question didn't specify if the $\nabla$ you were referencing was the Levi-Civita connection associated with a metric. The result is true for any affine connection. It can be derived from the fact $\nabla$ extends to a derivation on tensor fields which commutes with contractions.  If $C$ denotes contraction, you can derive the result from 
$0 = \nabla(1) = \nabla(C(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\otimes dx^i)) = C(\nabla(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\otimes dx^i))$ ( $C(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\otimes dx^i)) = \delta^i_j$)

Comment: thanks once again for your patience and help guys. I learned so much today, couldn‘t be more grateful.

Comment: @Zest you're welcome. I'm glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression is wrong. There are no derivatives of $\omega$ involved (also notice that there is no first derivative of $f$ in the last parcel of your formula). Recall that for a smooth local frame $\{e_1, \cdots, e_n\}$ the connection forms $\{\omega_{j}^{k} \}_{1 \leq k \leq n}$ are determined by $$\nabla_{e_i} e_j = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} \omega_{j}^{k}(e_i) e_k$$

Or, equivalently, $$\nabla e_j = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} \omega_{j}^{k}(\bullet) e_k$$

which is usually written as:

$$\nabla e_j = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} \omega_{j}^{k} e_k$$

In the case that the local frame is a coordinate frame (which is apparently the case you want), by definition
$$\omega_j^k(\partial_{i}) = \Gamma_{ij}^k$$
Now, since $\nabla^2 f$ is a $(0, 2)$ tensor and $\{ \mathrm{d}x^i \otimes \mathrm{d}x^j  \} $ forms a basis of the space of such tensors, we have:

$$\nabla^2 f = \sum_{1 \leq i, j \leq n} (\nabla^2 f)_{ij} \mathrm{d}x^i \otimes \mathrm{d}x^j $$

But

\begin{aligned}
 (\nabla^2 f)_{ij}  = \nabla^2_{\partial_i, \partial_j} f &= \nabla_{\partial_i} \nabla_{\partial_j} f - (\nabla_{\partial_i} \partial_j)f \\
&= \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i \partial x^j} - \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} (\Gamma_{ij}^k \partial_k) f \\
&=  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i \partial x^j} -  \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} \Gamma_{ij}^k \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}\\
\end{aligned}

Which can also be written as

$$(\nabla^2 f)_{ij} =  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i \partial x^j} -  \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} \omega_{j}^k(\partial_i) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}$$

So we have:

$$\nabla^2 f = \sum_{1 \leq i, j \leq n }\left(  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i \partial x^j}- \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}  \omega_{j}^k(\partial_i) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}\right)  \mathrm{d}x^i \otimes \mathrm{d}x^j $$

Clearly,

$$\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n}  \omega_{j}^k(\partial_i)  \mathrm{d} x^i = \omega_{j}^k$$

Therefore:

$$\nabla^2 f = \left( \sum_{1 \leq i, j \leq n } \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i \partial x^j} \mathrm{d}x^i \otimes \mathrm{d}x^j \right) - \sum_{1 \leq j, k \leq n} \frac{\partial f }{\partial x^k} \omega_{j}^k \otimes \mathrm{d}x^j$$

which can also be written as

$$\nabla^2 f = \left( \sum_{1 \leq i, j \leq n } \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i \partial x^j} \mathrm{d}x^i \otimes \mathrm{d}x^j \right) - \sum_{1 \leq j, k \leq n} \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x^k} \otimes \omega_{j}^k \right)(f, \bullet) \otimes \mathrm{d}x^j$$

**REMARK:** A vector field $X$ can be seen as a $(1, 0)$ tensor field, which acts on the space of $1$-forms $\Gamma(T^{*} M)$ by $X(\omega) = \omega(X)$. $\nabla X$ can be seen as a $(1, 1)$ tensor field: either by seeing it as a map which takes a vector field as input and outputs another vector field, os a map which takes as input a real smooth function and another vector field and outputs a real smooth function, that is:
\begin{aligned}
\nabla X: \Gamma(T^{*} M) \times \Gamma(T M) &\to \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M) \\
(\beta, Y) &\mapsto (\nabla_Y X)(\beta) = \beta(\nabla_Y X)
\end{aligned}

Now, if $V$ is a vector field and $\beta$ is a $1$-form, we have the tensor product $\beta \otimes V: \Gamma(T M) \times \Gamma(T^{*} M) \to \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$, which is a tensor field of type $(1, 1)$ given by $$(\beta \otimes V)(Z, \alpha) = \beta(Z)V(\alpha)= \beta(Z) \alpha(V)$$

In particular, $\nabla e_i$ is a $(1, 1)$ tensor field given by $$(\nabla e_i)(X, \alpha) = (\nabla_X e_i)(\alpha) = \sum_{1 \leq j \leq n} (\omega_i^j(X) e_j)(\alpha) = \sum_{1 \leq j \leq n} \omega_i^j(X) e_j(\alpha) = \sum_{1 \leq j \leq n} (\omega_i^j \otimes e_j)(X, \alpha)$$

Since $X$ and $\alpha$ are arbitrary, we can write:

$$\nabla e_i = \sum_{1 \leq j \leq n} \omega_i^j \otimes e_j$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Matheus for your detailed explanation, that is tremendously helpful. I really tried to get it done but as you noticed, I was somehow stuck on the wrong path. Please give me some time to work through the details of your answer, I will accept your answer soon. 

May I ask what the reason is that, say for your expression $\nabla e_j$ the right hand side is not written as a tensor product? I'm always confused by the different notations in differentialgeometry.

Comment: There are a lot of abuse of notations in differential geometry and a lot of times you have to figure out what the authors mean with the notation on a case by case basis. But after a while of this torture you get used to it and can usually tell from context

Comment: Thank you Matheus, I was just a bit confused (even though I got used to it somehow) that, for example, I've mostly encountered the expression $$\nabla e_i = \sum_j \omega_{ji}\otimes e_j$$ and it somehow made sense to me, but this would not satisfy the requirements you just mentioned, would it?

Comment: @Zest I actually made a mistake writing my previous comments, $\nabla X$ is a $(1, 1)$ tensor field, not $(1, 0)$, and so there is indeed a way to make sense of the expression you just wrote. I'll edit my previous comments and include a remark in my answer explaining how to make sense of this expression.

Comment: No worries, I really appreciate your time and effort, thank you so much!

Comment: @Zest see if the remark I just added is alright to you :)

Comment: Thank you Matheus, I will write it down and see if there are any more questions, but that was already incredibly helpful.

Comment: In your remark, did you possibly mean "$X(\omega) = \omega(X)$"?

Comment: @Zest I did, that was a typo. Thanks for letting me know, I'll correct it